# Math font with special K

Tags: fonts

Can somebody identify typeface that includes such k with small loop at the top-right? Example from school mathematics book (isbn 978-5-346-01428-7):

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like some Schoolbook font. For example TeX Gyre Schola Math gives the following result:

[image: Formula]

with this code (compile it using LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Tex Gyre Schola Math}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left(-\frac{3n^6k^3}{10p^4}\right)^3
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: There's also `fouriernc` for usage with `pdflatex`.