# Is there a way to use string manipulations to make macro names?

Tags: macros, strings

**Bottom line up front:**  what is a convenient way to input a particular character string into a `\newcommand` call so it can be manipulated to create multiple macro names?  In particular, input (say) ABC so that a savebox `\ABCbox` is created, from which a macro `\ABC` is then defined using `\ABCbox`, and returning that macro for repeated use later on.  I suspect I would prefer a Lua suggestion, but am a complete novice in how Lua interacts with LaTeX, so will likely need some hand-holding.

---

As a group theorist, I use "k" for conjugacy classes, but want one that is (in spirit) an overlay of `$\ell$` on `$\mathit k$` to have a loopy "k" in the same way `\ell` is a loopy "l".  Ultimately, I wrote tikz code that created the glyph I wanted, and wrote a `\newcommand` to name the macro `\kay` that printed that glyph.  However, I naively included the tikz code directly in the `\newcommand` call, which meant that the tikz code was newly compiled every time `\kay` was called, which was a few hundred times; compile times increased considerably.  Due to the answer given at [Long Compilation Time: Tikz Accents](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/576581), I discovered saveboxes, and compile times were demonstrably faster.

As an academic exercise, I then decided to create other personal glyphs using similar methods, and found myself reusing the same "boxing" code over and over in creating the corresponding saveboxes.  Hence, I wrote the following macro which would take as input the tikzpicture (and some other parameters) and output the corresponding savebox.

```
\newcommand\createABCbox[5]{%
\newsavebox#1
\savebox#1{%
\mathalpha{
\hspace{#2pt}
\raisebox{#3pt}{#5}%
\hspace{#4pt}}}}
```

The code would be used in the following way (consider this an MWE, the actual tikz code is much more elaborate):

```
\createABCbox{\ehhbox}{1}{1}{.5}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){\(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand \ehh{\usebox{\ehhbox}}
```

This got me to thinking.  While this greatly reduced the amount of work I needed by putting it in a macro call, there should be a way to get the obvious additional savings.  (As well, I suspect a solution to this problem will prove useful to another three situations I face.)  What I would really like is to make a command `\createABC` that takes as its first input just the character string "ehh" and somehow manipulates it to create the character strings "\ehhbox" and "\ehh", with the newly developed strings then being used at the LaTeX level as the actual macro names being defined.  Hence, running `\createABC` with input string "XYZ" would create the macro call `\XYZ` and the savebox `\XYZbox`.

As for my efforts in this direction, I have looked at the packages stringstrings and xstring, but both seem to deal more with strings which will be printed, rather than creating something that is recognized by a LuaLaTeX compiler as a macro name.  I do admit I didn't delve too deeply into either of these, so I may have missed something.

Ideally, I would like to perform this task in Lua (at which I am a complete novice), but

- I don't know the correct way to place an argument (in this example, #1) into a form Lua recognizes as a string, and
- every time I try to insert Lua code into a LaTeX `\newcommand`, I get an error.

As an example of the second point, using the package luacode, the code

```
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode}
tex.sprint("hello world")
\end{luacode}

\end{document}
```

compiles correctly.  However, if I wrap the Lua portion in a newcommand call such as

```
\begin{document}

\newcommand\AAA
{
\begin{luacode}
tex.sprint("hello world")
\end{luacode}
}

\AAA
\end{document}
```

I get the following error message.

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \luacode@grab@lines.
```

For completeness, the entire preamble presently is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{bm,comment,luacode,mathtools,scalefnt,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
```

Comment: The basic answer to your question is yes, and the basic method is to use `\csname ... \endcsname` or methods that use that. See [What exactly do \csname and \endcsname do?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/39380) for an introduction.

Comment: When in Lua, you could use `token.set_macro("AAA","hello world")` or `token.set_macro("AAA","hello world","global")` when no arguments are required

Comment: Wouldn't borrowing the k from another font be simpler? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/385574/math-font-with-special-k?

Comment: How to adjust things when using different font sizes? E.g., in normal size you might want spaces `#2pt` / `#3pt` / `#4pt`.  What spaces do you want, e.g., when `\huge` or `\scriptsize` is in effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is essentially the same as [@gernot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/624658/117050) but reduces the number of `\expandafter`s and `\csname`s making the code more readable, imho.

The approach uses two steps of processing, the first step just reads in the first argument (the others are curried) and creates the macro names from it, resulting in two new arguments. The next step then gets all the arguments.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\newABC[1]
  {%
    % #1: name for macro and box
    % #2: before   (curried)
    % #3: raise    (curried)
    % #4: after    (curried)
    % #5: contents (curried)
    \expandafter\newABC@\csname #1\expandafter\endcsname\csname #1box\endcsname
  }
\newcommand\newABC@[6]
  {%
    % #1: macro
    % #2: box-macro
    % #3: before
    % #4: raise
    % #5: after
    % #6: contents
    \newsavebox#2%
    \sbox#2{\mathalpha{\hspace{#3pt}\raisebox{#4pt}{#6}\hspace{#5pt}}}%
    \newcommand#1{\usebox#2}%
  }
\makeatother

\newABC{ehh}{1}{1}{.5}
{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0){\(h\)};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
A\ehh b
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As requested a few explanations on the code:

- `\csname` expands all following tokens until it finds an `\endcsname` and the result is turned into a control sequence.
- `\expandafter` steps over the next token (regardless which kind of token, an opening brace for instance is a token as well which could be stepped over with this) and expands the token after that one once (if that token isn't expandable nothing happens).

So `\expandafter\stuff\csname foo\endcsname` will result in `\stuff` being stepped over and `\csname` being expanded once. Within a single step of expansion `\csname` expands all following tokens until it finds an `\endcsname` and leaves everything in between as the name of a control sequence. In this case it'll find `foo` (letters don't expand further), and so after `\csname` is done the `\expandafter` will be removed from the input stream and `\stuff` put back, so the input will now contain `\stuff\foo`.

We can utilize the fact that `\csname` expands everything until it finds an `\endcsname` to build two control sequences at once (in the following the next thing TeX will evaluate will be preceded by `|>`  and the tokens stored to be put back because TeX stepped over them will be preceded by `||`  -- this is the same style the `unravel` package would use, though my steps might not be the same that package would show):

```
|> \expandafter\stuff\csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\csname bar\endcsname
```

will first step over `\stuff`, so the input will look like this (this is less than one step of expansion, more a step of processing):

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|> \csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\csname bar\endcsname
```

Now `\csname` will start grabbing/expanding tokens, and because of `\expandafter` the `\endcsname` will not be found, instead TeX steps over it and expands what follows:

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|| \csname foo\expandafter\endcsname
|> \csname bar\endcsname
```

Now the second `\csname` grabs/expands tokens until it finds `\endcsname` and turn the found string into a control sequence:

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|| \csname foo\expandafter\endcsname
|| \csname bar
|> \endcsname
```

and

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|| \csname foo\expandafter\endcsname
|| \bar
```

Now the second `\csname` is done with one step of expansion and the second `\expandafter` will be removed and the token which followed it put back, so the next step of processing would look like

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|| \csname foo
|> \endcsname\bar
```

The first `\csname` finally finds its `\endcsname` and this will become

```
|| \expandafter\stuff
|| \foo\bar
```

Now also the first `\csname` had its step of expansion from `\expandafter`, so it'll be removed and `\stuff` put back, so this eventually becomes

```
|> \stuff\foo\bar
```

and now `\stuff` can do stuff.

Even though the above was visualized in many small steps of processing when we look at expansion steps this is all done in a *single* step, because `\expandafter` will in a single step expand the `\csname` and that will fully expand the remaining stuff in this one step.

Comment: @JohnMcVey I agree, his answer is preferable for those reasons (and since he was faster to add these I didn't add them to mine).

Comment: @gernot no, it isn't. But as it currently stands your answer is the better one, even though the complete code might be less intelligible.

Comment: @gernot finally done.

Answer (score 0):

You can use macros with argument-specifier `c` provided by the expl3-programming-interface indicating that as argument the user provides a set of tokens whose total expansion yields the name of a control-sequence-token which during expansion is to be used in place of the corresponding parameter of the replacement-text:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \newABC #1#2#3#4#5 {%
  % #1: name of to-be-defined macro /
  %     prefix of name of to-be-allocated box-register
  %     ; for forming the entire name of the box-register 
  %       the phrase "box" is appended to the prefix
  % #2: measure related to unit pt of horizontal space prepended 
  %     to user-specified content of box
  % #3: measure related to unit pt of vertical space to raise 
  %     user-specified content of box upwards
  % #4: measure related to unit pt of horizontal space appended
  %     to user-specified content of box
  % #5: user-specified content of box
  \box_new:c{#1box}%
  \hbox_set:cn{#1box}{\mathalpha{\hspace{#2pt}\raisebox{#3pt}{#5}\hspace{#4pt}}}%
  \cs_new_protected:cpn{#1}{\box_use:c{#1box}}%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{tikz}

\newABC{ehh}{1}{1}{.5}{%
   \begin{tikzpicture}%
   \node at (0,0){\(h\)};%
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
A\ehh b
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If for whatsoever reason you don't like to use the expl3-programming-interface, I can offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` to create, e.g.,  the control-word-token `\ehh` from the character-token-sequence `ehh` or the control-word-token `\ehhbox` from the character-token-sequence `ehhbox`.

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

(`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` just triggers creation of the control-word-token `\foo` which after its creation will be processed by TeX in the usual ways.)

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}={bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\let\foo={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo...`  .

You can use `\CsNameToCsToken` for doing something like the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\makeatother


\newcommand\newABC[5]{%
  % #1: name of to-be-defined macro /
  %     prefix of name of to-be-allocated box-register
  %     ; for forming the entire name of the box-register 
  %       the phrase "box" is appended to the prefix
  % #2: measure related to unit pt of horizontal space prepended 
  %     to user-specified content of box
  % #3: measure related to unit pt of vertical space to raise 
  %     user-specified content of box upwards
  % #4: measure related to unit pt of horizontal space appended
  %     to user-specified content of box
  % #5: user-specified content of box
  \CsNameToCsToken\newsavebox{#1box}%
  \CsNameToCsToken\sbox{#1box}{\mathalpha{\hspace{#2pt}\raisebox{#3pt}{#5}\hspace{#4pt}}}%
  \CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{#1}{\CsNameToCsToken\usebox{#1box}%
}%

\usepackage{tikz}

\newABC{ehh}{1}{1}{.5}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node at (0,0){\(h\)};%
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
A\ehh b
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The problem with the environment `luacode` is the same as with environments like `verbatim` or `lstlisting`:

It expects the phrase `\end{luacode}` to be tokenized under some non-standard-catcode-régime, yielding a set of tokens differing from the set of tokens one would obtain by tokenizing under standard-catcode-régime.

If coming from the replacement-text of a macro `\AAA` whose definition-text was tokenized under standard-catcode-régime, then the phrase `\end{luacode}` won't be recognized as the end of the environment `luacode`.

As a workaround I can offer a routine

```
\DefineVerbatimToScantokens{⟨control-word-token⟩}{⟨xparse-argument-specifiers⟩}{%
  ⟨verbatim-material to be passed to \scantokens⟩
}%
```

*⟨verbatim-material to be passed to \scantokens⟩* is read and tokenized under verbatim-catcode-régime.

Then within *⟨verbatim-material to be passed to \scantokens⟩* every `#` is replaced by a character-token of catcode 6(parameter).

Then *⟨control-word-token⟩* is defined to process arguments according to *⟨xparse-argument-specifiers⟩* and to pass *⟨verbatim-material to be passed to \scantokens⟩* to `\scantokens`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
%\pagestyle{empty}
%\usepackage{bm,comment,luacode,mathtools,scalefnt,tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,calc}
\usepackage{luacode}

%=== Code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens ========================
% With older LaTeX-releases uncomment the following line:
%\usepackage{xparse}   
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineVerbatimToScantokens{mm}{%
  \begingroup
  \catcode`\^^I=12\relax
  \InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{#1}{#2}%
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\def\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens#1#2{%
  \endgroup
  \NewDocumentCommand\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{mm+v}{%
    \endgroup\ReplaceHashloop{##3}{##1}{##2}%
  }%
  \newcommand\ReplaceHashloop[3]{%
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\Hashcheck##1#1}$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {%
      \NewDocumentCommand{##2}{##3}{%
         \begingroup\newlinechar=\endlinechar
         \scantokens{\endgroup##1#2}%
      }%
    }{%
      \expandafter\ReplaceHashloop\expandafter{\Hashreplace##1}{##2}{##3}%
    }%
  }%
  \@ifdefinable\Hashcheck{\long\def\Hashcheck##1#1{}}%
  \@ifdefinable\Hashreplace{\long\def\Hashreplace##1#1{##1####}}%
}%
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\catcode`\#=12\relax
\InnerDefineVerbatimToScantokens{#}{%}%
%=== End of code of \DefineVerbatimToScantokens =================

\DefineVerbatimToScantokens\AAA{+v}{%
  \begin{luacode}
  tex.sprint("Hello World and #1!")
  \end{luacode}
}%

\DefineVerbatimToScantokens\BBB{+v+v+v}{%
  \begin{luacode}
  tex.sprint("Hello #1 and #2 and #3!")
  \end{luacode}
}%

\begin{document}

\AAA{John}

\BBB{Universe}{World}{John}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I don't know if allocating another box-register with each instance of `\newABC` really is the right way to go:

Storing things in box-registers means "casting font sizes etc in stone":

Maybe your command `\ehh` produces good-looking results while normalsize is in effect.
But what about situations where `\huge` or `\scriptsize` or the like is in use?

I recommend to take into consideration [the comment of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/624654/is-there-a-way-to-use-string-manipulations-to-make-macro-names#comment1559344_624654):

> Wouldn't borrowing the k from another font be simpler?